# how to calculate mode for a sorted array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mode

So I'm writing a method to calculate mode of a sorted array. But when i print out the mode value, it always comes out as 0.00, and i tried to fix it but could't. 
Here's my code for this method: 
(numRead is the passed array, num is the array length that actually have values)

```
public static void modeCalc(double[] numRead, int num)
    {
        double maxValue = numRead[0];
        int maxCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRead.length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numRead.length; j++)
            {
                if (numRead[j] == numRead[i])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = numRead[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `num` parameter? Also, this code doesn't compile, since you can't return a value from a `void` method.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed that to double. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You need to return a double, and you need to use num.

```
class ModeArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] numRead = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        System.out.println(modeCalc(numRead, 8));
    }

    public static double modeCalc(double[] numRead, int num) {
        double maxValue = numRead[0];
        int maxCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                if (numRead[j] == numRead[i]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = numRead[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

If you know the array is sorted, you should use this information.

```
public static double modeCalc(double[] numRead, int num) {
    double maxValue = numRead[0];
    double lastValue = maxValue;
    int count = 1;
    int maxCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (numRead[i] == lastValue) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
            lastValue = numRead[i];
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = lastValue;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

PS: Please don't use if-statement without braces. It makes it easier to add bugs, and harder to find them.

Comment: Why would you need nested loop to find mode of sorted list?

Comment: Better, but a bit long. [This](http://ideone.com/2vyCLx) is shorter and will return `NaN` if empty array is given, rather than throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Still got my up-vote.

Comment: True. If without braces is still evil though ;)

Comment: Only to people who are too blind to see that there is no end-brace when adding a second statement. I mean, the end-brace would have been right there on the very next line, so if you can't see that it's not there, you deserve what you get. ;-) To me, bracing single-statement, single-line code is a waste of vertical space. Not as bad as putting start-braces on their own line, which is truly evil, but...

Comment: There's a lot of posts saying it isn't a good idea. It's not really a personal preference, it's often dangerous, and not only to blind people.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. My professor said if there's only one statement, you can omit the braces for it. But it'll probably be better to have the braces all the time right.

Comment: I see it that way : Java is pretty verbose. The advantage is that it gives your IDE more information to find errors and bugs. For just 1 line less out of many, I don't want to make it easier to introduce bugs that I or the IDE won't be able to find. If you want compact code, use Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

a cursory glance suggests that your array has more 0 values at the end of the sorted data and these become the mode.  here is what appears to be the problem, it is stated that numRead is the sorted array, but it has only num values of significance.  the loops search the array to the end, not for the number of elements that have good values.  change numRead.length to num and see if that helps.  also, try passing a full array (no empty elements) and see if it works any better.  it is likely that the empty elements are initialized to zero and that there are more of these than any other value.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem! Thanks.